# laravel 5 auth changes to validator

Tags: validation, authentication, laravel, laravel-5

I removed the "name" column and added first and last name columns, now I'm getting a validator error from the registration view. I'm unclear from illumnate where the built in auth system is getting it's validation rules from.

How do I override?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default validation rules are defined in `App\Services\Registrar`. Just comment the `name` rule from the `validator` method and add your own `first_name` and `last_name` rules:

```php
public function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        // 'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: AHH there she is, I swear I looked there